# socket.io net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am creating a multiplayer game with login system. However, there is one error, which I don't know how to solve. When I run my app I get the following error:
net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED.

Here is my **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// Init App
var app = express();
 var http = require('http');
   var server = require("http").Server(app);
  var io = require("socket.io")(server);

// View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout:'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'views'));

// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

// Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

io.on('connection', function(socket) 
  {
console.log('New connection attempt');
  });


server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Server started on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

my **layout.handlebar**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap1.css' />
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />

  <title>IKTSL</title>

  <style>
    #question_options div button:nth-child(1){
      visibility: visible;
    }
  </style>
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:3000');
</script>

<div class="container">


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
{{#if success_msg}}
            <div class="alert alert-success">{{success_msg}}</div>
          {{/if}}

          {{#if error_msg}}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error_msg}}</div>
          {{/if}}

          {{#if error}}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
          {{/if}}


        </div>

        </div>


    </div> <!-- /container -->

        <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class='row'>
      <div class='span12'>
      <br>
      <br>
      <h1>I Know This Song Lyrics!</h1>
  <br>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class='row'>
      <div class='span4'>
      <div class='well'>
           <div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
           {{#if user}}
              <li role="presentation"><a href="/">Dashboard</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="/users/logout">Logout</a></li>
            {{else}}
              <li role="presentation"><a href="/users/login">Login</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="/users/register">Register</a></li>
            {{/if}}
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <h3 class="text-muted">Log in</h3>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class='span8'>
      <div class='hero-unit'>
      {{{body}}}
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class='span5'>
      <div class='users'>
      <h3>Players</h3>
      <div class="connectedUsers"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am just trying to console log "New connection attempt" when I starts working but that doesn't work.
I'll be grateful for any help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I believe you can change to this (remove the additional require of http and set io to listen to server):

```
// Init App
var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
```

If your client-side is running on a different port than your server, you should change your import as well, I think. Otherwise, that piece might be fine. I don't think you need the .connect on io in var socket = io.connect(); Mine is working without it, anyway.

```
<script src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
```